# Mongo Aggregation with count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Am trying to aggregate multiple collections and find the count of the duplicate occurrences using $match condition, but unable to do so.

My collections have the following fields:

```
db.book
{
    bookSerialNumber,
    ModelId, 
    ManufacturerId,
    details
}

db.bookIssue
{
    additionDate, 
    bookId, 
    StatusId, 
    TypeId, 
    ModelId, 
    issueCount 
}
```

In aggregation am matching modelId, ManufacturerId and bookId(db.book._id==db.bookIssue.bookId) from both collections:-

```
Result:
{
    bookSerialNumber,
    ModelId, 
    ManufacturerId,
    bookId,
    total_Count
}
```

can some provide me a proper solution for this?

Comment: Can you post your actual collection and output

Comment: above is my details

Comment: please post your actual collection copying from mongoshell